# Show only LTS updates for ASP.NET Core NuGet packages in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, lts

Having an ASP.NET Core project running on 2.1 LTS, I want to stay on LTS versions. So I'm not updating on 2.2 or 3.0 (both currently EOL) but an upgrade to 3.1 (next LTS) is planned in the future. Currently I want to stay on 2.1 LTS, which is [still supported up to August 21, 2021](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core).

The NuGet package manager of VS 2019 show me a lot of updates for 2.2! I have to check every single update if there are any 2.1.x fixes like in this example:

[image]

Here I have 2.1.11 installed and there is 2.1.16. I'd like to install 2.1.16 to apply the latest fixes and security patches. After updating from 2.1.11 to 2.1.16, NuGet still shows me an update to 2.2.5:

[image]

As you can see, the latest 2.1.x version is now installed, but NuGet still wants me to update on 2.2.5 (which is *not* LTS and 2.2 is also EOL since end of 2019).

#### How can I setup the VS 2019 solution to inform me about updates in the LTS branch (like 2.1.11 to 2.1.16: First screenshot) but not upgrades outside the LTS branch (Like 2.1.16 to 2.2.5 on the second screenshot)?

Comment: There is no such configuration option, mostly because NuGet versioning has no concept of what is LTS and what is not.