# Show only LTS updates for NuGet packages in Visual Studio

Tags: .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019

### Preamble

My org is low-risk so we're planning to stick to LTS releases (`.NET Core 3.1` at the time of this post.) The Nuget Package Manager Updates list, however, currently offers non-LTS updates (namely to `.NET 5.0`.)

### Question

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio in a way to show LTS updates only? Alternatively, is there any other way I can achieve the same desired result?

---

<sub>(This question is actually almost a copy of [Lion's original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427789/show-only-lts-updates-for-asp-net-core-nuget-packages-in-visual-studio), but I'm hoping that improvements on `api.nuget.org` or in the way Visual Studio handles API results may result in a viable answer.)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a real good question. And many community members want this feature on **PackageReference** for net core projects.

**In fact**, what you want is not supported on **PackageReference** so far. And net framework projects with `packages.config` nuget management format can realize it. See [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#floating-version-resolutions).

Under `packages.config`, you can use `allowedVersions` node for nuget packages on `packages.config` file, such as `[3.1.0, 5.0.0)`. It means `3.1.0` **<=** current version **<** `5.0.0`. You can only update the nuget package under that range on the **Nuget Package Manager UI**.

It is quite useful feature but **Microsoft** has not added this feature for the new-sdk project with **PackageReferece**. Therefore, many community members has raised [this issue on github](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6566) which is still in processing.

And [the Team has planned to fix the problem on December 20](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/milestone/118). So I suggest you could follow that github link and add any comments to describe your issue to raise more attention from **Microsoft**' team. All of them will help solve the problem as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the existence of that GitHub issue and I really appreciate you bringing that to my attention: I'll add my two cents later. Personally I think this problem could be better handled by the addition of meta-information about the LTS status - something like `allowedTags="['LTS','long-term-support']"` thus bypassing the need to know the version range, but that's a different can of worms.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. VS is not yet so flexible to keep nuget's version consistent with targetframeowrk LTS. So for now, we can only wait for Microsoft to add `allowversion` to `PackageReference`. And since what your suggested is another new feature, if you still want yours, I suggest  you could [suggest your idea on the DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8) to get their attention.

Comment: @OnoSendaim, since you cannot do anything more here on so and have to wait to the team's feedback, I suggest you could mark this answer to give other community members a right direction about this issue. And it is kind of you to do that.